# Delete and insert on same procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

In my SQL stored procedure, I need to delete and insert on same query. My syntax is below. But my syntax fails to store data. Why does it fail? How do I solve this problem? My syntax is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCollectionInspectionHours  
    @StartDate DATETIME ,  
    @EndDate DATETIME ,  
    @ID BIGINT ,  
    @VesselName VARCHAR(80) ,  
    @VoyageNo VARCHAR(15) ,  
    @PortCode VARCHAR(20) ,  
    @Terminal VARCHAR(70) ,  
    @InspectionDate DATETIME ,  
    @InvoiceHours INT ,  
    @ManifestType INT ,  
    @Remarks NVARCHAR(200)  
AS   
    BEGIN    

        BEGIN  


            DELETE  FROM dbo.InspectionHours  
            WHERE    InspectionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate   

        END  

        BEGIN  


            SELECT  @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1  
            FROM    [InspectionHours]    
            INSERT  INTO [InspectionHours]  
                    ( [ID] ,  
                      [VesselName] ,  
                      [VoyageNo] ,  
                      [PortCode] ,  
                      [Terminal] ,  
                      [InspectionDate] ,  
                      [InvoiceHours] ,  
                      [ManifestType] ,  
                      [Remarks]  
                    )  
            VALUES  ( @ID ,  
                      @VesselName ,  
                      @VoyageNo ,  
                      @PortCode ,  
                      @Terminal ,  
                      @InspectionDate ,  
                      @InvoiceHours ,  
                      @ManifestType ,  
                      @Remarks  
                    )    
        END  
    END
```

If have any questions please ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no error message.Just insert may not work .

Comment: Copy the code to a new query window, declare the parameters as variables and set them equal to some sample values.  Make sure you delete the "as" and "create procedure...." stuff.  Then run the query.  You should see error message showing you the line of any errors.

Comment: Also, what arguments are you calling the sp with? Are there any constraints on the table? And is the table initially empty? Do you get a value for @ID?

Answer (score 2):

check your id field identity property is true or not if it's true or yes then no need to give id in insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine.  This should not produce and error.

Your insert statement is also fine.  If it is not throwing an error then something else is going on.  Are you sure you are passing parameters?  Are you sure you are looking in the correct server/db/table and using the correct query to check?  Are you **positive** it's not throwing an error?